# Viewing SQL for SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) Transformations

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am new to Database and SSIS. Can anyone please let me know is there a way to look or view SQL code generated by SSIS transformations.
I know in BI reporting tools such as Business Objects, when we pull fields or columns into the reporting panel, we can view its corresponding SQL.
Similarly in SSIS, is there any option to view the SQL for SSIS Transformations.

Thanks in Advance
Raj

Comment: I'm not sure on side of SSIS, but you can turn on profiler on your database and catch it with this tool. 
Note: with profiler, you will catch all executing queries while he is turned on. Not be bad if you quickly turn on profiler, execute SSIS package and turn off profiler. After that just view what what has been executed.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS unlike other tools does not generate SQL per se, although you can include your own SQL inside tasks and components, but I guess you are not interested in the SQL that you write yourself but rather what SSIS is doing behind the scenes.

An SSIS package is essentially an XML-structured file with a collection of properties marking up the flow and process of its components. You can access to this xml file by right clicking on the package and selecting View Code:

[image]

The example above is an empty package so it's a very small XML file. In a complex package, this file can be very large as you will see all the tasks, components, parameters, variables, etc. as well as your own SQL code and C#/VB scripts if any.

When the project is built it generates a .ispac file which is no other thing that a zip file containing the package(s) in project plus a manifest, a content type and any other file required for the package to be deployed and executed.

You can see what is inside a .ispac by renaming to .zip and opening it. In this example I've built the above empty package and renamed the ispac to zip, then opened it :

[image]

In summary, unlike other tools that are purely SQL generators, in SSIS there is not much you can see about the generated code, all you can see is its structure as shown above.

Also, as mentioned by Marko Ivkovic in comments it might be possible to get some more info about what is happening at run time by using tools like SQL profiler.